# Verschleudern, verschwenden oder vergeuden

Tags: word-choice, synonym

> **verschwenden:** leichtfertig in überreichlichem Maße und ohne entsprechenden Nutzen verbrauchen, anwenden
>
> **vergeuden:** leichtsinnig und verschwenderisch mit etwas beim Verbrauch umgehen
>
> **verschleudern:** 1. 
>       (eine Ware) unter dem Wert, zu billig verkaufen
>       2. (abwertend) leichtfertig in großen Mengen ausgeben

Worin liegt der Unterschied dazwischen? Kann man *verschleudern* nur mit Geld assoziieren?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Verschwenden* ist der Oberbegriff, die andern beiden sind Spezialfälle davon.
Nach meinem Sprachgefühl gibt es folgende Unterschiede:

- Zeitraum: Bei *verschleudern* erfolgt die Handlung eher kurz und exzessiv, bei *vergeuden* eher über eine längere Zeitspanne.
- Aktiv/Passiv: *Vergeuden* hat einen Beiklang von Trägheit und Faulheit, *verschleudern* von hektischer Hyperaktivität.
- Gegenstand: Bei *Verschleudern* werden üblicherweise Geld oder andere materielle Werte verschwendet; *vergeuden* wird auch oder sogar hauptsächlich benutzt, wenn abstrakte Dinge wie Zeit oder Chancen verschwendet werden.
- Risikobewusstsein: Bei *Verschleudern* nimmt man eher als bei *vergeuden* an, dass der Verschwender weiß, welche riskanten Folgen sein Verhalten haben kann.

Comment: +1, nur bei dem Zeitraum-Argument stimme ich nicht ganz zu.